# SQL query: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
SELECT @Tax = SUM(QuoteItem.SalesPrice) * TOP (1) Tax.Amount 
FROM Tax INNER JOIN
      Job ON Tax.TaxId = Job.TaxId INNER JOIN
      Quote ON Job.JobId = Quote.JobId INNER JOIN
      QuoteItem INNER JOIN
      Room ON QuoteItem.RoomId = Room.RoomId ON Quote.QuoteId = Room.QuoteId
WHERE (Room.QuoteId = @QuoteId) AND (QuoteItem.UnitId = @UnitId)
    RETURN @Tax
```

---

Result:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_GetQuoteUnitTax, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.
```

Note, that when I omit the TOP(1) it says:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_GetQuoteUnitTax, Line 54
Column 'Tax.Amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in
either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I want to do is simple and you can see it from the query, I want to take all the QuoteItems' SalesPrice and multiply it with the Job's tax.

Comment: Why are you trying to run `TOP 1` on the tax.amount field?  Also, your SQL is missing the `QUOTEITEM` join criteria.

Comment: The reason is cuz of the error I get (Msg 8120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=137110:

```
SELECT @Tax = SUM(QuoteItem.SalesPrice * Tax.Amount)
```

Comment: That solves your errors, but it will only return one row - is that your desired output?

Comment: YES. @Tax was supposed to be a scalar value, Also you can see that I was expecting only 1 Tax, since I tried to do TOP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this in two separate queries. The first gets the tax amount:

```
select @tax = Tax.Amount
  from Tax
    inner join ...whatever else you need here...
  where ...
```

Note that you can't use the 'top' clause when setting the @tax variable value - you will need to do something in your where clause to select the value you want.

Then get the sales price:

```
select @sales = sum(QuoteItem.SalesPrice
  from ...
  where ...
```

Finally return the result:

```
return @tax * @sales
```